# How to actively filter in a range from a table into another sheet?

Tags: excel, filter

I'm trying to filter a range from a table into another worksheet, jsut like you would in google docs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I04Q6aSNaRGM2hI_pxzU2K6kq60epNNfidKaP-ql5cg/edit?usp=sharing

You can edit the data in the 2nd sheet and it is immediately updated in the first.

How can the same real-time behavior be achieved in Excel if I have a table with the same information?

Edit: Without the use of Power Query.

Comment: @pnuts What do you mean translations are off topic? In this case, I am using the google Sheet as an example of behavior I am trying to achieve in Excel, rather than going through the lengthy process of explaining it.

Comment: @pnuts I could provide hours of trying, but it would not be relevant and would just add clutter to the post, which is not recommended on SO. I am not looking for an entire program, I am looking for guidance on how this can be achieved in Excel. If I asked how to remove duplicates in an Excel filter, would you assume I want you to write a program for me? No, the answer would be to go to Advanced filters and select the "Unique Records Only" checkbox. How would that poster show "code" to prove he or she did work already?

Comment: If I wanted code, I would have tagged this as VBA, and provided my attempt.

Comment: @pnuts It's alright. Most of my rep is from Google Apps Script, where i usually go and script my own solutions if it's not built into google sheets. I'm hoping this can be done in Excel (using existing features), otherwise I'll be learning VBA pretty quickly.